# Cannot create new mailing

Tags: civimail

Our wordpress CiviCRM civimail has stopped letting us create new emails.
When I click on Create New,
the url changes to:
.../wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fa%2F#/mailing/new
and the screen remains blank.
If I try to re-use an old mailing,
the url changes to:
...wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fa%2F#/mailing/197

and the dialog box for editing a mailing does not show.
At the bottom of the screen I see an error message:
Notice: ob_end_flush(): failed to send buffer of zlib output compression (0) in
.../public_html/wp/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4609

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by modifying php.ini to disable zlib compression.